# In Page Class should the action methods have return type as class name or using void return type is a good practice?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, pageobjects

```
public class HomePage {

    public HomePage clickAboutUs1Link() {
        aboutUs1.click();
        return this;
    }

    public void clickAboutUs1Link() {
        aboutUs1.click();    
    }
}
```

I will be calling the action method in my Test Class. So is there any advantage or disadvantage of using any one over the other when using Page Object Model with Selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question will be more clear if you had more methods. Consider those classes

```
public class HomePage {

    public AboutUsPage clickAboutUsLinkAndGoToAboutUsPage() {
        aboutUs1.click();
        return new AboutUsPage();
    }   

    public HomePage typeToField() {
        aboutUs1.click();
        return this;
    }

    public HomePage clickOnChecbox() {
        aboutUs1.click();
        return this;
    }
}

class AboutUsPage {

    public boolean isAboutUsPageDisplayed() {
        return someElement.isDisplayed();
    }
}
```

Now you can use method chaining in the test to create a flow

```
public class TestAboutUsLink {

    boolean isDisplayed =
    new HomePage()
        .typeToField()
        .clickOnChecbox()
        .clickAboutUsLinkAndGoToAboutUsPage()
        .isAboutUsPageDisplayed();

    assertTrue(isDisplayed);
}
```

And if every method didn't return anything

```
public class TestAboutUsLink {

    HomePage homePage = new HomePage();
    homePage.typeToField();
    homePage.clickOnChecbox();
    homePage.clickAboutUsLinkAndGoToAboutUsPage()

    AboutUsPage aboutUsPage = new AboutUsPage(); 
    boolean isDisplayed = aboutUsPage.isAboutUsPageDisplayed();

    assertTrue(isDisplayed);
}
```

This is subjective issue, but I find it clearer to have the test flow with implicit page objects creation (as far as the test concern) than breaking it to parts.

Comment: In the method chaining example , I don't understand how you are calling isAboutUsPageDisplayed() without the AboutUsPage object.Is this possible?

Comment: @Aditya There is `AboutUsPage` creation, in `clickAboutUsLinkAndGoToAboutUsPage()`. It initialized there and returned to the test.